# Can we use cloud functions alongwith mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have read many example and articles on this,till now I got to know cloud functions uses firebase database either firestore or real time database.But ,I want to know if it is possible to use mySQL database and use cloud functions with node.js script as backend?

And then I will use this cloud function in my flutter app.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A working example with Google Cloud Functions at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/functions/sql.

Comment: This is in python which is not my cup of tea.Do you know some other links in nodejs?

Comment: easy, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/functions/sql

Answer (score 3):

You can do most things in Cloud Functions that you can do in server-side Node.js, Python, or Go (the languages supported for Cloud Functions)
You can access Cloud SQL (MySQL or PostgreSQL) but you can also access any other server exposed to the Internet from Cloud Functions.

To be able to access servers outside Google Cloud, you need to use have paid Firebase plan though.

Comment: Can you provide any document which specifies how to exactly use it

Comment: That's quite broad. Just look up how to use MySQL from Node.js (if JS/TS is the language you want to use) and then post more concrete questions if you're stuck.

Comment: I know how to use this  MySQL from Node.js. Is this the same way we can use with cloud functions and mySQL?